# Using Backstretch for different images for individual pages

Tags: php, wordpress, image, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-backstretch

I hope there's someone out there that can help. I am trying to use jQuery Backstretch to apply a different background image for each specific page within Bootstrap/Wordpress. e.g:

Home - bg image a
About - bg image b
News - bg image c
and so on...

I've managed to use the standard Backstretch script to display a single image for all pages, but I am totally lost (even after searching) on how to apply the the above.

My code so far:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://myurl.co.uk/wp-content/themes/wpbootstra/bootstrap/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $.backstretch("http://myurl.co.uk/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/bootstrap/img/test_bg.jpeg");
</script>
```

I have used this in my footer.php.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
<?php
if(is_page(42))
{
    echo '<script>$.backstretch("http://myurl.co.uk/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/bootstrap/img/test_bg.jpeg");</script>';
} 
else if(is_page(41))
{
    echo '<script>$.backstretch("http://myurl.co.uk/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/bootstrap/img/test_bg_b.jpeg");</script>';
}
?>
```

The number 42, 41 being the id of the page. Sp text_bg_b.jpeg will only display on the About us page (assuming its id is 41).

Comment: Thanks Howlin.  Where would your suggested code sit within my previous example?  What parts to I replace? Sorry for the 'paint by numbers' request :)  Dezza.

Comment: Try replacing your last "script" with the above.

Comment: Works :) Thankyou very much Howlin.  You've just relieved two days of brain hurt!

Answer (score 1):

1. I think there is no need for using backstretch: Just add this css styles inline to your body or main container:

   `background: url(PATHTOYOURIMAGE) center center no-repeat;`

   `background-size: cover;`
2. You should consider using a custom field for giving the path to your image. I think the easiest way is to install [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) and to add a field called `bg_image` to every site with the image url in it. Then you can replace `PATHTOYOURIMAGE` with

   `<?php the_field('bg_image'); ?>`

It is another way but I think you should give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Radscheit.  Ok, i'm having difficulty working out what you've suggested.  I've placed the .css in my main style sheet (bootstrap.css), does <?php the_field('bg_image'); ?> sit inside the brackets or replace the whole background: css line?  Ive also installed ACF and created a bg_image field with a return value - image url.  I'm assuming this needs to be exported as .php and placed in each page?  I dont get how I can reference a different image for each page.  Do you have a working example I could view?  Sorry, this is all very new to me.  Dezza.

Comment: Hej, in order to make it work you have to apply this style inside the tag and not in an external style sheet.

Please note that `<?php the_field('bg_image') ?>`is just a placeholder like `the_content()`. Once implemented it gets automatically the right image url of the image that you have defined in your backend. So you better log into your wordpress, take a random site and look up if there is a field below the editor for adding an image. Add one, save and finish :)