# Serving a different set of images for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, responsive-design, jquery-backstretch

I'm using [jQuery-backstretch](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-backstretch/info) to serve fading background images on my page. This works well for desktop, but because of how detailed these images are, I need to use another set of of images for mobile users only.

So far I found out how to disable the script for mobile (or use different images for individual pages: [Using Backstretch for different images for individual pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012717/using-backstretch-for-different-images-for-individual-pages)), but I would love to find out how to serve a totally different set of images just for mobile.

```
<script>
function detectmob() {
  if(window.innerWidth <= 800 && window.innerHeight <= 600) {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
}

if(!detectmob()){

    $.backstretch(["imgs/1.jpg"
, "imgs/2.jpg"
, "imgs/3.jpg"
, "imgs/4.jpg"
], {duration: 1800, fade: 4000});
}
</script>
```

Does anyone has a solution? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You somehow have to detect the viewport size and invoke backstretch based on that.

Instead of doing that by checking the window width, you can use [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia).

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)").matches) {
 // phone
$.backstretch(["imgs/1_phone.jpg"
, "imgs/2_phone.jpg"
, "imgs/3_phone.jpg"
, "imgs/4_phone.jpg"
], {duration: 1800, fade: 4000});

} else {

//tab or desktop
$.backstretch(["imgs/1.jpg"
, "imgs/2.jpg"
, "imgs/3.jpg"
, "imgs/4.jpg"
], {duration: 1800, fade: 4000});


}
```

You could do something like this.

Comment: This would solve my issue. I tried the code now, but somehow it doesn't work properly. Backstretch doesn't show any images anymore. Here's the sample website with the code. http://wuel.avx.pl/ Any clues? Thank you.

Comment: jquery &backstretch are not loaded.. there is also a syntax error in the solution I gave in the answer, which I have corrected now..

Comment: It works perfect now. Thank you. I only edited the first line of the code, from `if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)").matches) {
 // phone` to `if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 992px)").matches) {
 // phone`